# Display PDF files on map using OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers, layers, pdf

I have a PDF file containing geographic images. I want to show it on the map but haven't found a solution yet.

I tried this way:

```
    const imgExtent = [0, 0, 1024, 968];
    const projection = new ol.proj.Projection({
        units: 'pixels',
        extent: imgExtent
    });
    let imglayer = new ol.layer.Image({
        source: new ol.source.ImageStatic({
            url: 'img/geographic.pdf',
            projection: projection,
            imageExtent: imgExtent
        }),
        // minZoom: 15
    });
    map.addLayer(imglayer);
```

but the desired result is not achieved, only JPEG, PNG,... images are displayed.

How can I display PDF files on map?

Comment: That's not possible as ImageStatic source doesn't accept PDF files, it depends on standard HTML image so only [these formats](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Media/Formats/Image_types) are accepted. In case your file is GeoPDF you could convert it to GeoTIFF (using QGIS) and display it like in [this example](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/cog.html), if not export your images from PDF and use them directly like in [this example](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/static-image.html).

Comment: You could use a third-party library such as PDF.js to convert a standard pdf to a canvas, then use the canvas data url as the url for the ImageStatic as in https://codesandbox.io/s/static-image-forked-hx0d2h

Comment: @geraldo I'm not sure if my PDF file is GeoPDF or not. I tried the above two examples but didn't get the desired result.

Comment: The example from @Mike works fine for me and is the way to go.

Comment: @Mike it solved my problem and works perfectly, thank a lot.